# Difference between various WSDL to client stub code generator?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, apache-axis, webservice-client

What are the different WSDL to client stub code generator and their differences? Which one is better if I need to translate a complex WSDL into code? By complex, I mean the WSDL has various contraints such min and max length/ value, min and max occurrences.

As of now, I know 3 tools that can do the job from Google and StackOverflow: `Axis2`, `CXF`, `Eclipse WTP` and `IBM Rational`. I was only able to test Axis2. I have no experience on CXF and IBM Rational. What are the differences of the said tool? Is there any other good tool that you can suggest?

I tried to generate a server stub from WSDL using Axis2 before but one web service method is not generated so I've stopped using Axis2 thinking that there might be a limitation on the code genaration of Axis2. Is there a limitation on the code genaration of Axis2? The one I tried before is a server stub. Now, I need to generate a client stub.

Please note that we are using JDK 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse WTP just calls out to either Axis 2 or CXF depending on which you need/have installed.

CXF's code generator is completely compatible with JAX-WS (and the wsimport command), but also runs fine with Java 5.  By using CXF, you can certainly run on Java 5 now and if/when you move to Java 6, you can then decide at that point to flip to the JAX-WS impl in the JDK or stick with CXF.   You'd have that choice.   With Axis 2, you'd be stuck with Axis 2.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't manage to stumble across the default JAX-WS implementation in the jdk (based on [metro](http://metro.java.net/guide/))?

Comment: No. Does Java has its own tool for client stub generation given the WSDL file? Please not that I need to generate a client stub not create a web service.

Comment: Are you referring to wsimport? I've checked it but it says that it only became available starting on JDK 1.6. We are using JDK 1.5 so I don't think we can use it.

Comment: @Arci - yes, jaxws has client and server support.  no, i don't think it is included with jdk 5 (it is included with jdk 6), but i believe you can use metro with jdk 5.